# Regular Expressions: What does the \A tag do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Explain this regex used in RoR /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
What does the \A tag do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\A` and `\Z` markers are meant to provide a way to identify the start and end of a string, primarily for multi-line strings.

If you're processing one line at a time (which is mostly, but not completely, the case with UNIXy text processing tools), you could simply use `^` and `$` because start/end of string is the same as start/end of line.

For example, the single string:

```
This is line 1
and this is line 2
```

would have *two* matches for `^`, one before `This` and one between `1` and `and`. It would only have *one* match for `\A`, before `This`.

Answer (score 1):

Start of a string.

See the ["Permanent Start of String and End of String Anchors"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) section

Answer (score 0):

[As Chris Diver said, start of a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287866/regular-expressions/3287900#3287900)

You can experiment with Regular Expressions at http://rubular.com.